# How to fix Error C2504: base class undefined?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2019

I have two ***.h** files, one of them contains inherited class definition of another files class.

I check all **#include** directives, but i don't see cycling.

First file **Data.h**:

```
#pragma once

#include <cinttypes>
#include <string>

// all class data
struct SData {
public:
    // constructors
    SData() : sStub("") {};
    SData(const std::string& s) : sStub(s) {};
    // data
    std::string sStub;
};

class Data {
private:
    // data
    int32_t iID; // unique ID of data entity
    SData _sData;
protected:
    // functions
    void SetID(const int32_t& _iID) {
        iID = _iID;
    };
public:
    // constructors
    Data() : iID(0), _sData("") {
    };
    explicit Data(const int32_t& _iID) : iID(_iID), _sData("Data class Stub") {
    };

    // destructor
    ~Data() {
        iID = -1;
    };

    // functions
    int32_t GetID(void) const {
    return iID;
    };
    virtual const SData* GetData(const uint32_t& uiType) const {
        return &_sData;
    };
};
```

Second file **OSData.h**:

```
#pragma once

#include "Data.h"

// all class data
struct SOSData : public SData {
public:
    // constructor
    SOSData() : SData(), sOSStub("") {};
    SOSData(const std::string& s) : SData(s), sOSStub(s) {};
    // data
    std::string sOSStub;
};

class OSData : public Data {
private:
    // data
    SOSData _sData;
public:
    // constructors
    explicit OSData(const int32_t& _iID) : Data(_iID), _sData("OSData class Stub") {
    };
    // functions
    const SOSData* GetData(const uint32_t& uiType) {
        return &_sData;
    };
    // data
};
```

**main.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "OSData.h"

int main()
{
}
```

So, i don't have any other files in project, and compiler shows 2 errors:

```
Error   C2504    'Data': base class undefined   SystemInfo  D:\VS_Workspace\SystemInfo\SystemInfo\OSData.h

Error   C1075    '{': no matching token found   SystemInfo  D:\VS_Workspace\SystemInfo\SystemInfo\OSData.h
```

Can someone please point me to right direction with this problem?

Comment: See the second error message and count braces in the headers.

Comment: Just a nitpick but do not put semicolons after function definitions. Please provide a [mcve], [cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/9jfchPcv4).

Comment: Can't reproduce. I copied this source locally and compilation was successful.

Comment: yes, i copied the code from this page to IDE and it miracly compiles.

Comment: [Can't reproduce, either](https://onlinegdb.com/lFHuSVgME)

Comment: Huge thanks everyone for getting into my problem, i suppose it can be something on my side, like some random symbol from another locale.